# react; Parallel Async/Await getting data, but undefined in setState()

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise, setstate

I am trying to do async/await calls in parallel rather than one by one, but I'm getting the error below.
How can I fix this?

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, 
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

**below code works fine**

```
state = {}
async componentDidMount () {
  const global = await fetchSummary()
  const countries = await fetchSummaryByCountry()
  const dailyData = await fetchCountryHistory()
  const accessedCountry = await fetchCountryName()

  this.setState({
    global: { ...global },
    dailyData: dailyData,
    accessedCountry: accessedCountry,
    countries: countries
  })
}
```

**below code gives error**

```
state = {}
async componentDidMount () {
  const [global, countries, dailyData, accessedCountry] = await Promise.all([
    fetchSummary(),
    fetchSummaryByCountry(),
    fetchCountryHistory(),
    fetchCountryName()
  ])
  this.setState({
    global: global,
    dailyData: dailyData,
    accessedCountry: accessedCountry,
    countries: countries
  })
}
```

Weirdly, both codes pass down the props correctly, but the upper one produces an error and the page doesn't render.
Also, is there a better way to solve this one?

Thanks in advance for taking your time on this.

Comment: Promise.all([
    fetchSummary(),
    fetchSummaryByCountry(),
    fetchCountryHistory(),
    fetchCountryName()
  ]).then(val=>{console.log(val)})

Can you please run the code and tell the result